# Calculate time between two different values in the same pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have data that look like the following

```
Device     Time        Condition
D1  01/11/2019 00:00    issue
D1  01/11/2019 00:15    issue
D1  01/11/2019 00:30    issue
D1  01/11/2019 00:45    issue
D1  01/11/2019 01:00    issue
D1  01/11/2019 01:15    Resolved
D1  01/11/2019 01:30    Resolved
D2  01/11/2019 01:45    issue
D2  01/11/2019 02:00    Resolved
D1  01/11/2019 01:45    issue
D1  01/11/2019 02:00    Resolved
```

I need to create a new column that will find the time between the first issue and the first resolved.
I need a groupby statement that will keep the first issue and the first resolved for all the issues. Then find the time - When I use group by Device and condition it just kept one issue per device.

The desired output is like the following

```
Device  Time    Condition   durationTofix
D1  01/11/2019 00:00    issue   
D1  01/11/2019 00:15    issue   
D1  01/11/2019 00:30    issue   
D1  01/11/2019 00:45    issue   
D1  01/11/2019 01:00    issue   
D1  01/11/2019 01:15    Resolved    01:15
D1  01/11/2019 01:30    Resolved    
D2  01/11/2019 01:45    issue   
D2  01/11/2019 02:00    Resolved    00:15
D1  01/11/2019 01:45    issue   
D1  01/11/2019 02:00    Resolved    00:15
```

As groupby Device and Condition is not enough I thought to create an index column

```
data["index"] = data.groupby(['Device','condition']).??? #Something like cumcount() but it is not cumcount in this case
```

Then use pivot table for the time calculations

```
H = data.pivot_table(index=['index','Device'], columns=['condition'], values='Timestamp',aggfunc=lambda x: x)
H['durationTofix'] = H['Resolved']- H['issue']
```

Comment: Please add the code you already tried. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: You could apply a shift on ``Time and Condition``, filter out rows with ``issue and Resolved`` then find the time diff.

Comment: There is always at least one `issue` before `Resolved` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem is how to group your issues/resolved properly, which can be done by a reversed `cumsum`:

```
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"])

df["group"] = (df["Condition"].eq("Resolved")&df["Condition"].shift(-1).eq("issue"))[::-1].cumsum()[::-1]

df["diff"] = (df[~df.duplicated(["Condition","group"])].groupby("group")["Time"].transform(lambda d: d.diff()))

print (df)

   Device                Time Condition  group     diff
0      D1 2019-01-11 00:00:00     issue      2      NaT
1      D1 2019-01-11 00:15:00     issue      2      NaT
2      D1 2019-01-11 00:30:00     issue      2      NaT
3      D1 2019-01-11 00:45:00     issue      2      NaT
4      D1 2019-01-11 01:00:00     issue      2      NaT
5      D1 2019-01-11 01:15:00  Resolved      2 01:15:00
6      D1 2019-01-11 01:30:00  Resolved      2      NaT
7      D2 2019-01-11 01:45:00     issue      1      NaT
8      D2 2019-01-11 02:00:00  Resolved      1 00:15:00
9      D1 2019-01-11 01:45:00     issue      0      NaT
10     D1 2019-01-11 02:00:00  Resolved      0 00:15:00
```

Comment: Thx. It is short and smart :> . But I can not fully understand the first line. I hope if u can explain it

Comment: `pd.to_datetime`? or the `cumsum` part?

Comment: Sorry I meant cumsum :)

Comment: The conditions are 1. column value is "resolved" and 2. the next column value is "issue". With that you receive a boolean series, however you need to count it from backwards to properly group the cases together. so `[::-1]` to reverse the array, `cumsum` to get the group numbers, and another `[::-1]` to assign it back. Its basically a reversed `cumsum` but there is no parameters in `cumsum` for this.

Answer (score 1):

Solution if there is always at least one issue before `Resolved` per consecutive groups by `Device`:

```
#converting to datetimes
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

#consetutive groups
g = df['Device'].ne(df['Device'].shift()).cumsum()
#test issue values
m = df['Condition'].eq('issue')
#replace not issue to missing values
i = df['Time'].where(m)

#get first duplicated rows by consecutive groups and condition column
mask = ~df.assign(g=g,i=i).duplicated(['g','Condition']) 
#forward filling Time by first issue per groups
s = df['Time'].where(mask & m).groupby(g).ffill()

#subtract and filter only first Resolved per groups
df['durationTofix'] = df['Time'].sub(s).where(mask & df['Condition'].eq('Resolved'))
print (df)
   Device                Time Condition durationTofix
0      D1 2019-01-11 00:00:00     issue           NaT
1      D1 2019-01-11 00:15:00     issue           NaT
2      D1 2019-01-11 00:30:00     issue           NaT
3      D1 2019-01-11 00:45:00     issue           NaT
4      D1 2019-01-11 01:00:00     issue           NaT
5      D1 2019-01-11 01:15:00  Resolved      01:15:00
6      D1 2019-01-11 01:30:00  Resolved           NaT
7      D2 2019-01-11 01:45:00     issue           NaT
8      D2 2019-01-11 02:00:00  Resolved      00:15:00
9      D1 2019-01-11 01:45:00     issue           NaT
10     D1 2019-01-11 02:00:00  Resolved      00:15:00
```